# Unable to add button on top right inside UITextView programmatically in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitextview

the textview is dynamic, which contains a button on top right corner. it works for textfield. not showing button in textview..

Awaiting....

```
class CommonTextView: UITextView {

private let microphoneButton = UIButton(type: .System)

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    initTextView()
}

func initTextView() -> Void {

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 7

    microphoneButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //microphoneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
    microphoneButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "mic"), forState: .Normal)
    microphoneButton.tintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    microphoneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.microphonePressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.addSubview(microphoneButton)

    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: microphoneButton, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: microphoneButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: microphoneButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: microphoneButton, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
    self.addConstraints([trailingConstraint, topConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])

}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I've updated the code

Comment: Can you click on the general location where your button should be? Does it have any effect?

Comment: Button is not visible and no effects. But the same code works for textfield

Comment: Justo to clarify -- you have a UITextView with a button *inside* it? Or is it on *top* of it?

And are you using storyboards or just doing everything programmatically?

Comment: I'm adding a button as subview in uitextview programmatically. And it works for uitextfield

Comment: I never wrote constraints programatically, but I believe the width and height are missing the `toItem` parameter.
Have you tried passing the button itself instead of nil?

Comment: I think that textfield works because the edges grow from the content inside but the button does not.
Just a guess, though. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's too complicated to deal with NSLayoutConstraint. Instead, try this simple Anchor layout code. Replace everything under self.addSubView to these simple five lines of code

```
let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
microphoneButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
microphoneButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
microphoneButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
microphoneButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

Comment: I've replaced with your code. but button is not visible. Now it's not visible for textfield also.

Comment: @jayaraj Then the problem is not the button is self. Can you post more code related to the button please?

Comment: @jayaraj Oh you want this button on the text view? Have you tried to set the top anchor to 0? In my answer I set it to 100 and if your text view is shorter than 100, it will show off screen

Answer (score 0):

**See for the proper Constraints rightAnchor to textView not working give it self.view.rightAnchor**

[image]

***Black Part is textView and Orange part is Button***

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true


        textView.addSubview(button)


        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        **button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true**
        view.bringSubview(toFront: button)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    let textView: UITextView = {
        let label = UITextView()
       // label.text = "Jeevan Chandra Tiwari"
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        label.textColor = .white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = .orange
        button.setTitle("Click Me", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()



}
```